# PowerBi Local Folder Timeout

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

I have a folder on my local machine which is about 1GB in size and my publish does not work due to this.

My question is, Is there a way to set the timeout for the folder sources in the M Code?

This is how my source line looks like

`Source = Folder.Files("path/to/data"),`

**I will write a song in your name, if you get me its answer.**

Comment: Afaik you can not, but as a workaround, you can serve this folder in a local web server (i.e. ngnix or apache) with directory index, and use the timeout option of Web.Page...

Comment: @KemalKaplan, I really appreciate your answer. I have never worked on making my own server. Please tell me what I need to look at and would it be able to support 3GB?

Comment: The answer depends on where do you experience the timeout. If your folder have thousands of small Excel files, I can suggest you to use the proposed method for loading the index page. But if you have a few very very large Excel files, maybe the timeout should be used while opening the files instead of loading the index file...

Comment: Yes, my folder has thousands of 300Kb csv files. about 100 such files files become part of everyday.